# PostgreSQL Query by substring in a join table returns partial values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I am trying to write a join query to search by a certain substring a certain column

I have 3 tables:

```
SELECT PE.* FROM SCHEMA.PERIPHERAL_TYPE AS PE

    left JOIN SCHEMA.TENANT_PERIPHERAL_TYPE AS TPT ON (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_ID = TPT.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_ID)
    left JOIN SCHEMA.TENANT AS T ON (TPT.TENANT_ID = T.TENANT_ID)

    where
    LOWER(CAST (T.TENANT_NAME AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%'AND 
    LOWER(CAST (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_ID AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    LOWER(CAST (PE.DEVICE_TYPE AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    LOWER(CAST (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_NAME AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    LOWER(CAST (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_BRAND AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    LOWER(CAST (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_MODEL AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    LOWER(CAST (PE.PERIPHERAL_TYPE_DESC AS TEXT)) LIKE '%%' AND
    TO_CHAR(PE.CREATED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') LIKE '%%' AND
    TO_CHAR(PE.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') LIKE '%%' )
```

And here is my db:

`TENANT             TENANT_PERIPHERAL_TYPE                     PERIPHERAL_TYPE
======             ======================                     ================
id: 1 name: ss     [tenantId: 1, peripheral_type_id 1 ]       [peripheral_type_id: 1, ...]
                                                              [peripheral_type_id: 2, ...]
                                                              [peripheral_type_id: 3, ...]`

This query works fine if I provide a value for **TENANT_NAME** column, for example `%name%`. I am getting only the matching `peripheral types`.

But when I don't provide any value (like you see in the query above), I am getting only records available
in the **TENANT_PERIPHERAL_TYPE**, but I would like to get all the values from **PERIPHERAL_TYPE**

What am I missing and how can I solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of all these `LIKE '%%'`?

Comment: I am searching by a substring value, %% means all values

Comment: And it also means `IS NOT NULL` by requiring that _some_ string be present.

Comment: If you have a `LEFT JOIN` and then `WHERE` condition on a field from the **right** table you effectively convert it to `INNER JOIN`.  `NULL` is not equal or `LIKE` anything, including another `NULL`.

Comment: so what could be the solution in this case to get all the values from PERIPHERAL_TYPE table?

Comment: Why do you need the where clause at all, if you want all the values? Or at least, why do you need each specific condition?